# toml crate how to structure dependencies-like struct

Tags: serialization, rust, deserialization, toml

I have a toml file in form of:

```
[general]

loaded=true
can_reload=true

[dependencies]
```

The `dependencies` section works essentially the same way as `Cargo.toml` dependencies, each dependency is listed on a separate line.

The problem is, that when using the [toml crate](https://docs.rs/toml/0.5.8/toml/) to serialize/deserialize it, I'm not sure how to specify a section that can have any number of entries with any name below it.

My structure currently looks like:

```rs
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Configuration {
    general: ConfigurationGeneral,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct ConfigurationGeneral {
    loaded: bool,
    can_reload: bool,
}
```

I saw on the documentation that you can use `Option` but that's still just for a single value. There's no way I can know the names of the dependencies and how many there will be to add them to a struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Represent `dependencies` with a `HashMap`:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize}; // 1.0.126
use toml; // 0.5.8

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Configuration {
    general: ConfigurationGeneral,
    dependencies: HashMap<String, String>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct ConfigurationGeneral {
    loaded: bool,
    can_reload: bool,
}

fn main() {
    let config: Configuration = toml::from_str(r#"
        [general]
        loaded = true
        can_reload = true
        
        [dependencies]
        toml = "1.4"
    "#).unwrap();
    
    println!("{:#?}", config);
}
```

See it on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c3607ee22cf245feab2d3876270afe7a).

Here I'm just parsing the dependencies with the values as `String`s but they can of course be more complex structures as well.